# Json-Deserialization adds default values to parsed class and thus destroys ModelState-Validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am using .net 5.0 and AspNetCore.

I want my API to receive a JSON Body that is being converted to a class. I do this by using following code in my controller:

```
[HttpPost("languages")]
public IActionResult Update([FromBody] LanguagesDto updatedDto)
{
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           // Log Error and return BadRequest
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }
      // Do something
      return Ok();
}
```

Lets say this is my DTO-Class:

```
public class LanguagesDto
{
        [Required]
        public bool English{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Spanish { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool French { get; set; }
}
```

With above code, I would expect the ModelState to be invalid, when one of the properties is missing in the json body.
So this JSON should return a bad request.

```
{
   "english": true
}
```

but what happens instead is, that the default values for booleans are being added to the object and thus the ModelState being valid!

I have tried to use different Attributes but it didn't work out. Any idea?

Comment: It's case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

change LanguagesDto to this :

```
public class LanguagesDto
    {
        [Required]
        public bool? English { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool? Spanish { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool? French { get; set; }
    }
```